# Does batch normalization work on balanced dataset?

Tags: tensorflow

I trained a classification network using tensorFlow with batch normalization in every convolutional layer. When I predict on a balanced test set where every category included in it, the accuracy is normal. **However**, if I chose any one specific category from test set, the accuracy is low, even zero.
But when 3 categories included in test set, the accuracy became higher. As we all know, the weights was fixed when the model finished training. But I find the balance in test set have greatly influence on prediction accuracy.
I think if batch normalization has influence on this, so I remove all batch normalization and retrained the model again. This time, when I predict only one category picture, it became normal.
Could anyone know why? THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. If your training set is unbalanced you compute and accumulate mean values (for every layer) that are skewed in favor of the majority class.
In fact, you're not "normalizing" but instead, you're making the unbalancing problem worse.
Use batch normalization when you have a balanced training set and you can be sure that your batches will contain a balanced number of samples. This gives you optimal results.

However, since you added in the comments that you're using `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(x, num_output, kernel_size, stride, padding, activation_fn, normal_fn=tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm)`

I spotted the problem: `normalizer_fn` calls the function you pass (batch_norm). But it uses the defaults parameters. By default, `is_training` equals to `True` thus you're computing even during the test phase the mean and the variance over the batch. Just read carefully the documentation of `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d` and use `normalizer_params` to pass `is_training=True` when training and `is_training=False` when testing/validating.

Comment: THANKS! er……actually I trained the model on balanced dataset, every mini-batch is also balance. But when I evaluate on an unbalanced test set, for example, only one class in test set, the accuracy is very low. When I remove batch normalization, the phenomenon disappear. So how do I get normal performance on test set with only one class, and do not need to remove BN ?

Comment: This makes no sense. Are you sure that you're using the computed (during the train phase) means and variances and not computing them on the current evaluation batch?

Comment: I use ```tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(x, num_output, kernel_size, stride, padding, activation_fn, normal_fn=tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm)```  an when I evaluate, I restore the checkpoints and set ``` reuse = False``` . I think the mean and variance which BN computed in training procedure are also fixed in evaluation procedure.

Comment: Spotted the problem: `normalizer_fn` calls the function you pass (`batch_norm`). But it uses the defaults parameters. By default, `is_training` equals to  `True` thus you're computing even during the test phase the mean and the variance over the batch. Just read carefully the documentation of `tf.contrib.layers.conv2d` and use `normalizer_params` to pass `is_training=True` when training and `is_training=False` when testing/validating.

Comment: THANKS VERY MUCH, I have found it.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll update the answer with this last part. If I solved your problem please remember to mark this answer as accepted!